# PHP: generated CSV file doesn't have any header?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm creating a simple CSV file using PHP from MYSQL database.

The CSV file gets created fine and the content is where they need to be but the CSV file doesn't have any header!

this i smy code:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $rows = mysqli_query($db_conx, 'SELECT u.email as referrer, 
                                        ref.email as referred 
                                    from users u 
                                        INNER JOIN users ref 
                                            on u.ref_code=ref.ref_code_used');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {


      fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    exit();

?>
```

The header of the CSV should be `referrer` and `referred`... and i thought this would do it:

```
SELECT u.email as referrer, ref.email as referred from users u INNER JOIN users ref on u.ref_code=ref.ref_code_used
```

But this doesn't put the header in the CSV file.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could your lack of column headings be something to do with the fact you have not attempted to place any column headings in the output?

Comment: Why would there be magical column headers when you only loop through the data and write that to the file? ;)

Comment: You need to actually build column header first, THEN loop the rows and put them in.

Comment: try `fputcsv($output, array_keys($row));` in your first loop iteration, I leave it to you how to figure out it's only printed once :D

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah I was to fast, corrected.-.-

Comment: You seem to be expecting `fputcsv` to be much smarter than it is. It's a really dumb function and does only exactly what you tell it to. And you're not telling it to output any headers at any point.

Comment: @clearshot66, thanks for talking to me like a human and without any sarcasm... based on your help I figured out how to do it and added an answer as well... cheers mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $rows = mysqli_query($db_conx, 'SELECT u.email as referrer, ref.email as referred from users u INNER JOIN users ref on u.ref_code=ref.ref_code_used');

    $headers = "referrer, referred";
     fputcsv($output, explode(', ', $headers));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {



      fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this. First we check if you have output headers. If not, use the array_keys function to print headers.

```
$headers = false;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {

  if (!$headers) {
    fputcsv($output, array_keys($row));
    $headers = true;
  }

  fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```